# Не запускается симулятор androidа

Tags: windows-7

При запуске выдает следующие сообщения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Предлагаю не использовать папку с русским текстом в её имени.

Желательно ещё и без пробелов.

Comment: Да, русские буквы известная проблема, сам с ней сталкивался. С пробелами помнится работает.